# Basic Java, how to declare these Android functions

Tags: java, android, nfc

I have some documentation that doesn't have any intuitive examples for me

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/tech/NfcV.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/Tag.html

I need to declare objects of type `NfcV` and of type `Tag` , but when I try to do something like `NfcV myNFCObject = new NfcV();` the IDE says "constructor NfcV is not visible. So my next try looked like this `NfcV myNFCObject = NfcV.getTag(new Tag());` and I get the error "constructor Tag()" is not visible.

So thats where I hit a wall, just from looking at both of the documentation links, I do not see how to declare these objects! How would this be done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you must create a class which implements TagTechnology interface. Then you can get tag with it.

```
import java.io.IOException;

import android.nfc.Tag; 

public class sampleTagTech implements android.nfc.tech.TagTechnology {

public void close() throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void connect() throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public Tag getTag() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

public boolean isConnected() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

}
```

then you can use like this

```
NfcV nfcv = NfcV.get(new sampleTag().getTag());
```

Comment: thanks! I copied this but now I get a null pointer exception on `NfcV nfcv = NfcV.get(new sampleTag().getTag()); ` , this is probably because getTag() returns null, but I'm not sure how to handle this. Perhaps only call this function when a tag is discovered? Insight appeciated

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation you can do this:

```
NfcV object = NfcV.get(myTag)
```

Also there is no `public` constructor for myTag (which is why you get an error saying it is not visible it could either be `private` or `protected`) per the documentation you provide:

When a tag is discovered, a Tag object is created and passed to a single activity via the EXTRA_TAG extra in an Intent via startActivity(Intent).

Comment: myTag cannot be resolved to a variable. How do I declare a Tag object

Comment: All I can do is `Tag myTag = null; NfcV.get(myTag);` but this is a null object :( so I'm a little concerned about exceptions here

Answer (score 0):

When you hold an ISO15693-compliant tag near an NFC-enabled Android device, an intent will be created by the Android system. This intent will contain a handle for the tag. When your app receives the intent, it can retrieve it from there. See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/nfc/nfc.html#filtering-intents for a good explanantion on how to receive NFC intents in your app.

In the activity that receives the NFC intent, you can get access to NfcV like this:

```
Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
NfcV nfcV = NfcV.get(tag);
if (nfcV != null) {
  ...
}
```